# Did I ever ask a question about Microsoft OneNote 2016?

Tags: discussion

As at Jan 15 2019, StackExchange doesn't let users see questions that aren't recently deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, [there seems to be this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1219410/how-to-delete-simultaneously-all-section-groups-to-eschew-deleting-each-separat)

It was roombaed - probably cause it was just a screenshot and a title and downvoted.